# What to do if rust module function is private

Tags: rust

I wanted to use qoi in my rust project and tried this module, `https://github.com/ChevyRay/qoi_rs`
The problem is that, when I write this:

```
use qoi::Pixel;
```

The error :

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `qoi::Pixel`
 --> src/create_images.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use qoi::Pixel;
  |     ^^^^^-----
  |     |    |
  |     |    help: a similar name exists in the module: `pixel`
  |     no `Pixel` in the root

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `Thing_in_rust` due to previous error
```

so I tried `pixel` :

```
use qoi::pixel;
```

And this error message pops up

```
error[E0603]: module `pixel` is private
  --> src/create_images.rs:4:10
   |
4  | use qoi::pixel;
   |          ^^^^^ private module
   |
```

I am new to rust, but looking at the github code `https://github.com/ChevyRay/qoi_rs/blob/main/src/pixel.rs` gave me the impression that it is public.
cargo.toml :

```
[dependencies]
qoi = "0.4.0"
```

Comment: `use qoi::Pixel` should work. Can you include the full error?

Comment: You have defined a different crate(which is [qoi-rust](https://github.com/aldanor/qoi-rust)) in your `cargo.toml`, it needs to be renamed as `qoi_rs = "0.1.1"`

Comment: Sounds like the answer, but it doesn't know qoi_rs::Pixel.

Comment: 4 | use qoi_rs::Pixel;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Pixel` in the root

Comment: Looks like I also pointed to the wrong crate, I  don't know if this crate is even published on crates.io, you can inlcude this dependency via github link please check cargo doc to see how its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crate you've linked to doesn't seem to be published on crates.io, although there's a multitude of qoi crates over there.

So your options are either:

- use one of the crates which is published on crates.io
- use a direct [git dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories) rather than a cargo one
- a variant of the second one is to vendor the crate using a [path dependency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies) in case you need to update it

Comment: qoi = {git = "https://github.com/ChevyRay/qoi_rs", branch = "main"} worked for me